# WebUSB: How to call event listener with button press from Arduino

Tags: javascript, arduino, webusb

I'm trying to make an external controller with the WebUSB API. I want to take the button state from my Arduino board and translate that to a button press in chrome. (ex: when I press the button thats on pin 8, I want to make a div element red and when I release it changes back to its original sate.) The only problem is I don't know how to call such an event.

So far i've been using the example given by the webUSB page: https://webusb.github.io/arduino/

Comment: `i've been using the example` - does it work?

Comment: It does. However, like the example is ment to do, i'm able to turn on and off LED lights on my arduino board from my chrome tab but I don't know how to add the necessary code to do the opposite (send a commande from my arduino to chrome).

Comment: https://github.com/webusb/arduino/blob/gh-pages/demos/console/console.js#L46 could be a clue - along with https://github.com/webusb/arduino/blob/gh-pages/demos/console/sketch/sketch.ino

Comment: I don't get how to rewrite it into what I want.

Comment: the javascript or the c++?

Comment: The javascript. Right now I've got it running in a way that the terminal receives the button input from my arduino. Lets say I want a small div element to turn red when I press it, how would I go abouts doing so?

Comment: @NikolasSigouin can you please put your code into the question, so that we can take a look of what you already have?